# XLSX file uploaded to S3 has problems

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I'm uploading files using boto:

```
self.s3_client.upload_file(filename, self.bucket_name, key)
```

I then generate url:

```
url = self.s3_client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',
                                            Params={'Bucket': bucket,
                                                    'Key': filename},
                                            ExpiresIn=expires_seconds)
```

This URL is then passed to the users. I am having problems with XLSX files. After downloaded, either using the generated url, or directly downloaded from AWS S3 website, when  I try to open the file with excel, I get this message:

[image: "We found a problem with some content in . Do you want us to try to recover?"]

Clicking `No` just abandons the attempt of opening the file, so I click `Yes`, and then it says it was `able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content` and it gives me the following report:

> Repair Result to mcx-x_4ede8f96-e381-11eb-a788-3a54d470f35a1.xmlErrors
> were detected in file
> '/mcx-x_4ede8f96-e381-11eb-a788-3a54d470f35a.xlsx'Removed
> Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part

The file was generated by xlsxwriter, and it has just numbers, text, and dates. No formulas. Also, there should be no sheet named `sheet2`.

This doesn't look good for my application, and also I'm worried that maybe some data is getting lost, and the users will not get all the data they request.

What could be causing this problem?

Are there specific characters in the text that could be problematic?

What can I do?

Comment: Is the file you download the same size as the file you uploaded?

Comment: I don't know what the size is supposed to be. I pull the data from the database and generate XLSX, and upload it. I can add code that will check the file size on the /tmp...

Comment: @jmcnamara Interestingly, downloaded file is 15.1 MB, and repaired file is 14.4 MB

Comment: The repaired size isn’t helpful since it will vary with the Excel version. Check the uploaded size versus the downloaded size. If they are different then there is a issue with transferring the Excel binary file in upload or download. If the file sizes are the same then the issue should be in the xlsx file and not related to S3.